# Pandas column sort within a group, ignoring other columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I have to sort a column within a pandas df by a grouped variable id. The sort will not change the order of any other variable, other than it's own (sq3).

My data looks like

```
index id sq1 sq2 sq3
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1
2   0   0   2   2
3   0   0   3   3
4   0   0   5   5
5   0   0   4   4
6   0   0   6   6
7   0   0   7   7
8   0   0   8   8
9   0   0   9   9
```

And I want to achieve

```
index id sq1 sq2 sq3
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1
2   0   0   2   2
3   0   0   3   3
4   0   0   5   4
5   0   0   4   5
6   0   0   6   6
7   0   0   7   7
8   0   0   8   8
9   0   0   9   9
```

I have tried the following code that worked, but takes a very long time.
Any improvement will be greatly appreciated!

```
df_groups = df.groupby(['id','sq1'])

for name,group in df_groups:
df_groups.apply(lambda x: x['sq3'].sort_values(ascending=False).values)
```

Comment: you could pass it to a numpy array, sort it there and just re-assign it back to a pandas column? (assuming you are just sorting by that single column) some sample data and output would be nice.

Comment: Why not just: `df_groups = df.sort_values(['id', 'sq1', 'sq3'], ascending=False).set_index(['id', 'sq1'])`?

Comment: @PMende - that will not work for my purpose. I am making a copy of sq2 into sq3 and want to independently sort sq3 to see the break-point. Let me update with some data points

Comment: @qqplot I think perhaps you're misunderstanding what your operations imply. Groupby-sorting is the effectively the same as sorting by all 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `transform`

```
df.groupby(['id','sq1']).sq3.transform(sorted)
```

---

#### Demo

```
df.assign(sq3=df.groupby(['id','sq1']).sq3.transform(sorted))

       id  sq1  sq2  sq3
index                   
0       0    0    0    0
1       0    0    1    1
2       0    0    2    2
3       0    0    3    3
4       0    0    5    4
5       0    0    4    5
6       0    0    6    6
7       0    0    7    7
8       0    0    8    8
9       0    0    9    9
```